# fig/link-util not compatible with psr/link

Tags: php, symfony, php-psr

I installed a fresh Symfony v5.3, ApiPlatform v2.6.6. When I enter to `/api` url I'm getting that error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Fig\Link\Link::withHref(Stringable|string $href):
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader must be compatible with
Psr\Link\EvolvableLinkInterface::withHref($href) in
/api-platform-course/vendor/fig/link-util/src/Link.php on line 22
```

I opened that file with editor: `vendor/fig/link-util/src/EvolvableLinkTrait.php` and it is implementing that interface: `Psr\Link\EvolvableLinkInterface`. It seems this trait isn't correctly implementing methods. For example interface's method is this:

```
public function withHref(string|\Stringable $href);
```

`EvolvableLinkTrait::withHref` method implementation is this:

```
public function withHref(\Stringable|string $href): static
```

As you can see original method hasn't `static` keyword but implementation has. I removed the `static` return type hint from implementation but I'm getting same error still. Then I removed all type hints from implementation and error is gone. My current implementation is that:

```
public function withHref($href)
```

Everything fine for this method. Other methods has same problem too and I fixed with same way (`withRel()`, `withoutRel()`, `withAttribute()`, `withoutAttribute()` methods).

I'm using PHP 8.0 and Nginx server. What do you offer for this problem? Must I change package versions or lower Symfony version or anything else? Thanks.

Comment: I looked to composer-lock.json file and I see that fig/link-util version 1.2.0 loaded. I installed 1.1.2 version and everything is fine now. 1.1.2 version hasn't type hints, 1.2.0 has. Actually type hints seems correct but I didn't understand the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `fig/link-util` may need to update the package constraints.

`fig/link-util:1.2.0` is type hinted which means its should have
`"psr/link": "^2.0.0"` as a required package not `"psr/link": "^1.1.0 | ^2.0.0"`
it also says it provides a 1.0 psr/link-implementation but that should say 2.0.